# Develop UI software without the forms designer?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I am interested in developing software like Text Editors and so forth.

The only way I currently know how to develop software in C# is to use Visual Studio's Forms designer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVxli.png

In Java it is possible (and I know how to) to do this.

Is it possible to develop software in C# like how it is done in Java (through 100% code).

Comment: Huh? What does "forms" mean? Are you asking whether it's possible to make a UI without a UI?

Comment: Don't use Forms, use Windows (WPF) :P

Comment: Are you asking about a console UI? Yes, that's possible.

Comment: "The forms feature"? Again, be more specific. WPF could be considered "forms", and there's "web forms".

Comment: I mean't visual studio's form feature.

Comment: What is the `forms feature`? Winforms? Webforms? Wpf?

Comment: Which one? What project type did you pick to create a project using this "forms feature"?

Comment: Visual C# or Visual Studio does not have a forms feature. The .NET Framework comes with two toolkits for desktop UIs (and others for web-based projects) that Visual Studio provides direct access to via its GUI, and other such toolkits are available from 3rd parties.

Comment: To develop a text editor, you would have a form with a toolbar and text area on it... is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: I edited it to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: WinForms is 100% code. You simply use the editor in VS to save the headache of doing everything manually. You can write custom controls if you like, or you can override paint events and just draw everything. Without understanding more about what you're trying to accomplish, it's tough to provide guidance.

Comment: @TrentonPottruff: Oooooh ... now it's clear what you are asking. You want to know whether you can design a UI in Visual Studio without using the WYSIWYG designer. I have voted to reopen your question, but it would still be helpful if you made your question text yet somewhat clearer.

Comment: Is this the kind of Java UI code you're talking about? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33536/An-Introduction-to-Java-GUI-Programming

Comment: That's exactly what WinForms is like - the forms editor just generates that code for you. You can write it yourself if you prefer.

Comment: @TrentonPottruff - Yes, as the others have said, you can create you GUI completely with code, without using the Windows Forms designer.  Do this:  Create a simple form _with_ the designer and then look at the .designer.cs file.  That will show you what code the designer creates when you use it.  You can create your own code if you wish, but the designer makes it much more convenient!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is very possible. The forms designer is just a visual wrapper that generates code behind the scenes. You can use WPF that is a declarative approach to UI design. You can do the same with WinForms. Here is a simple form example written by hand. Besides practice though, I don't see why you would want to do this for non-trivial UI applications.

```
namespace MyTestApp
{
    public static class Program
    {
        [System.STAThread]
        private static void Main ()
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new MyForm());
        }

        public class MyForm: System.Windows.Forms.Form
        {
            private System.Windows.Forms.Button ButtonClose { get; set; }
            private System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox RichTextBox { get; set; }

            public MyForm ()
            {
                this.ButtonClose = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
                this.RichTextBox = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();

                this.ButtonClose.Text = "&Close";
                this.ButtonClose.Click += new System.EventHandler(ButtonClose_Click);

                this.Controls.Add(this.ButtonClose);
                this.Controls.Add(this.RichTextBox);

                this.Load += new System.EventHandler(MyForm_Load);
            }

            private void MyForm_Load (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {
                int spacer = 4;

                this.RichTextBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(spacer, spacer);
                this.RichTextBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(this.ClientSize.Width - this.RichTextBox.Left - spacer, this.ClientSize.Height - this.RichTextBox.Top - spacer - this.ButtonClose.Height - spacer);

                this.ButtonClose.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(this.ClientSize.Width - this.ButtonClose.Width - spacer, this.ClientSize.Height - this.ButtonClose.Height - spacer);
            }

            private void ButtonClose_Click (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {
                this.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, when  using the designer, take a look at the FormName.Designer.cs file which contains the same initialization code as above.